# replacing a value in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, replace

I'm writing a bingo game in python. So far I can generate a bingo card and print it.
My problem is after I've randomly generated a number to call out, I don't know how to 'cross out' that number on the card to note that it's been called out.

This is the ouput, it's a randomly generated card:

```
B   11  13  14  2   1   
I   23  28  26  27  22  
N   42  45  40  33  44  
G   57  48  59  56  55  
O   66  62  75  63  67
```

I was thinking to use random.pop to generate a number to call out (in bingo the numbers go from 1 to 75)

```
random_draw_list = random.sample(range(1, 76), 75)
number_drawn = random_draw_list.pop()
```

How can I write a funtion that will 'cross out' a number on the card after its been called.
So for example if number_drawn results in 11, it should replace 11 on the card with an x or a zero.

Comment: This would depend on the data structure you're using to represent the card.  (Hopefully there *is* some data structure, rather than you just generating and printing random numbers as you go.)

Comment: I have a function that stores the card in a dictionary and prints it